# Cloud function that logs current seconds on firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setinterval, google-cloud-functions

I would like to create a firebase cloud function that updates the current second on the real time database, every second.
As far as I understand I am not able to use setInterval because the function will stop after x seconds anyway.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve that using cloud functions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in interval based trigger in Cloud Functions for Firebase.

You can build cron-style triggering using other Google services, such as App Engine Cron (as shown in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html)) or an external web service (as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA)).

But neither of those seems particularly well suited for triggering every second. For that kind of constant load, I'd consider spinning up a Node.js process that simply uses `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.